# MouseEvent does not fire when implemented by a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jcomponent, mouselistener

Okay, so in this program I'm making, users will be able to create shortcuts to their favorite apps on their computer. My program will be kind of like a hub, I guess, for apps. I have a small problem though, which involves two classes: `AppButton` and `AppButtonContainer`. They both implement `MouseListener`, but `AppButton` extends `JComponent` and `AppButtonContainer` extends `JPanel`. Basically, when an AppButton is clicked, it sets a draws the border in a different color to make it look selected. Otherwise, it sets the border to the background color. When you double click it, it opens up the application specified. I have a method in `AppButton` to remove the focus, and therefore setting the border to the background color. In `AppButtonContainer`, there is a bit of code so that when, the panel is clicked, it removes the focus from the `AppButton`.

That's my problem, though. The `AppButtonContainer` doesn't realize that it's clicked. I'm thinking it has something to do with top level containers or something, but I'm not sure. Can anybody help?

**EDIT: I found out that I didn't put the `addMouseListener(this)` in the constructor of the AppButtonContainer. Thank you for everyone who helped me clear up this problem and give me tips along the way :)**

`AppButtonContianer`:

```
public class AppButtonContainer extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6485231881729120957L;
public List<AppButton> appButtons;
private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(18, 18, 18);

public AppButtonContainer(List<AppButton> buttons) {
    this.appButtons = buttons;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 20, 20));
    addButtonsToPane();
}

private void addButtonsToPane() {
    List<AppButton> buttons = this.appButtons;
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        this.add(buttons.get(i));
    }
}

private void removeAllButtonFocus() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.appButtons.size(); i++) {
        this.appButtons.get(i).removeFocus();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Pane Clicked");
    removeAllButtonFocus();
}

    ...Other MouseEvent methods
```

Comment: We're going to need that code.

Comment: Do you really expect us to guess what's wrong without code? What other special powers do you imagine we have?

Comment: right maybe there is someone that post you code,

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that you might not need the code for some reason. That just doesn't make sense now...

Comment: Don't use a `MouseListener`.  Instead have `JButton` instances using the app. icon as the button icon.  Add an `ActionListener` which is keyboard focusable, and reacts to both the enter key as well as mouse clicks.  For an app. that uses other components to launch documents in their default program, see [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui").  It uses `FileSystemView` to get the icons.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That was my initial thought, but I needed to make a more custom component. I see where you would think that would be better, but I don't think that would be good for my purposes. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: The linked example includes the source, so customize as needed!  Give it purple stripes if you want.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, added code.

Comment: You want to get the program logic and operational code out of your `paintComponent(...)` method. This method should be for painting and painting only. And ***never*** call `repaint()` from within this method. Ever.

Comment: um.... also, where do you call `addMouseListener(...)`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't think you had to add a mouse listener, since it was implemented by the class. **EDIT** Sorry, Tharwen explained it.

Comment: @whowantsakookie: Do you see how there would be no way to guess what the problem could possibly be without your code? Please keep this in mind for your future questions, and we all may avoid a bit of frustration, plus you'll likely get your correct answer quicker. Consider checking out [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) for more tips on how to ask questions that are easier to answer. Luck.

Comment: Also, your `paintComponent(...)` method is still way off the mark, and you'd better fix it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What do you mean by that?

Comment: The `paintComponent(...)` method should be for painting only, not for doing program logic or making non-painting method calls. For e.g., don't call setBorder(...), don't call `repaint()` inside of it. I'm suspicious about your calling `new File(...)` in it and suspect that this should be called in another method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, thanks for clearing that up. Someone answered by saying that and then removed his answer. I forgot who it was, though. He said that I shouldn't call `repaint()` inside it. But yeah, I've did what both of you have suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem at hand by putting `addMouseListener(this)` in the constructor for your AppButtonContainer class. Otherwise, it'll never pick up mouse events.

Generally, though, it's not good to turn your classes into mouselisteners like that. Perhaps try making an inner class to listen for mouse events and pass them to the AppButtonContainer instead.

Comment: Thank you! I though that you could just implement it and it would do it by itself. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: No problem. When you implement `MouseListener`, it turns that class into a handler for mouse events from any class, which is why you need to explicitly say that you're listening to events from the Listener itself.